# How to give custom error message if file not found

Tags: vb.net

I have a module in vb.net as shown below

```
Module Module1
    Public dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
    Public dbSource = "Data Source = C:\PMDatabase\MyDB.mdb"
End Module
```

it loads database based on the location I set in **dbSource** , the problem is when file is not Found it give an error message exposing the expected location of database file as shown below

**Could not find file 'C:\PMDatabase\MyDB.mdb'. Microsoft.Jet Database Engine**

I want the error message to simply show "**Database not found**"

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using a `try ... catch` block? I assume that this is producing an Exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Exception Handling (`Try Catch`) like this :

```
Try

    'your code (Open database).

Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Database not found")
End Try
```

You can keep the Exception line as well. (You can have as many Catch parts as you want.) This will Catch any other errors that may occur:

```
Try

    'your code (Open database).

Catch ex As OleDbException
    MessageBox.Show("Database not found")
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: Thanks, the solution you proffered is an eye opener to using Catch. I never  considered using catch like this. It works.

Comment: Good! I'm glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you defer the initialization of your dbSource variable to a later time? If so, then put the offending code (assigning a value to dbSource) in a try catch block, catch the exception and display the proper message accordingly.